# Tuncate a table in Azure SQL database through azure machine learning experiment

Tags: sql, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Azure machine learning studio to create some predictions, at the end of pipeline I need to truncate previous data in a Azure sql table and then write the new prediction, this is going to happen on a daily basis. How I could truncate a table from an experiment, it seems that there were a solution with reader component in Azure ML classic, but it is not working from current ML studio?

Answer (score 0):

In the reader write the truncate table and table name and it will execute.

```
Truncate table table_name;
```

Comment: Hi Sairman, I think this reader component is for ML classic, it is not available in new ML studio. In new ML studio we have a Import data component that we could run sql script, but when I use truncate table script it gives error! Do you have any idea about this?